# Control virtualbox from mac with python3

Tags: python, virtualbox

As the title states: I wish to send commmands via xboxapi to virtualbox. I want to use python3. I have install pyvbox and have vboxapi python3 constants, but when vboxapi tries to connect to virtualbox it cannot find the [python bindings](https://github.com/JshWright/vboxweb/blob/master/xpcom/vboxxpcom.py). Looking at `/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS` I can only see:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   219K 21 Dec 02:56 VBoxPython2_6.so
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   219K 21 Dec 02:56 VBoxPython2_7.so
```

Can someone help me make bindings for python3 for vitualbox?